# How to compute the expected number of duplicates

Tags: probability, expectation

Consider $n$ objects each with an associated probability $p_i$, $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.  If I sample objects  $k$ times independently with replacement according to the probability distribution defined by the $p_i$, how does one compute the expected number of times you sample an object you have sampled before?

We can assume that $n > k$.

Comment: Why the close vote? Is the question unclear?

Comment: Let $N_i$ denote the total number of times item $i$ is sampled and $R_i$ the number of times item $i$ is sampled while already sampled once, then $$R_i=\max(N_i-1,0)=N_i-1+\mathbf 1_{N_i=0}$$ and $N_i$ is binomial $(k,p_i)$ hence $$E(R_i)=E(N_i)-1+P(N_i=0)=kp_i-1+(1-p_i)^k$$ Summing these over $i$ yields the mean number of times one samples an item already sampled as $$E(R)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(kp_i-1+(1-p_i)^k\right)=k-n+\sum_{i=1}^n(1-p_i)^k$$

Comment: @Did That's really lovely. Could you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i = 1$ if the $i$th number sampled has already been sampled before, and $X_i = 0$ otherwise. Then we are looking for $E(X_1 + \cdots + X_k) = E(X_1) + \cdots E(X_k)$. Now, $E(X_1) = 0$, since $X_1 \equiv 0$. If $i > 0$,
$$
P(X_i = 0) = \sum_{j = 1}^n\underset{\substack{\text{not choosing item $j$}\\\text{on the first $i-1$ times}}}{\underbrace{(1 - p_j)^{i-1}}}\underset{\substack{\text{choosing item $j$}\\\text{on the $i$th time}}}{\underbrace{p_j}}.
$$
Therefore $E(X_i) = 1 - \sum_{j = 1}^n(1 - p_j)^{i-1}p_j$.

Summing up, we find that
$$
\begin{align}
E(X_1) + \cdots + E(X_k) &= E(X_2) + \cdots + E(X_k) \\
&= k - 1 - \sum_{i = 2}^k \sum_{j = 1}^n (1-p_j)^{i-1}p_j \\
&= k - \sum_{i = 1}^k \sum_{j = 1}^n (1-p_j)^{i-1}p_j \\
&= k - \sum_{j = 1}^n p_j \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} (1-p_j)^i \\
&= k - \sum_{j = 1}^n p_j \frac{1 - (1-p_j)^k}{1-(1-p_j)} \\
&= k - n + \sum_{j = 1}^n (1-p_j)^k
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Does your answer work out as the same as Did's?

Comment: @Lembik: I wasn't able to obtain Did's form, but I was able to obtain a similarly elegant final form. I've added the calculations to my post.

Comment: Pick one $p_j$ which is small and set $k=n$. It seems that a single term in your sum $\approx 2^{n-1}$. This can't be right can it or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Lembik: You're right. I've made a mistake in the calculations. I've corrected.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to me. Set $k=100$ and let $p_1 = 0.01$. Your sum is at least $0.01*(2-0.01)^{99} \approx  3.9 * 10^{27}$ and $100$ minus this is a very negative number. It would make sense to compare your answer to Did's numerically for a sanity check.

Comment: @Lembik: OK, I've found the error, and now I get Did's answer. I mistakenly summed up a geometric progression as though it was a binomial sum.

Comment: @Lembik: Unless you have any further issues, please accept my answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Re-sampling $m$ objects means sampling $k-m$ unique objects, which means avoiding $n-(k-m)=n+m-k$ unique objects, so using inclusion-exclusion, we can write $$E_k(m)=\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\left\{m\sum_{u=0}^{k-m}\left[(-1)^u{n+m+u-k \choose u}\sum_{J\subseteq I; |J|=n+m+u-k}\left(1-\sum_{j\in J}p_j\right)^k\right]\right\}$$That's a long way from a closed form solution, but it is at least an expression for the value that you want.

**Edit**: Not much point to this since there are two answers nicer than mine now, but I just realized you can do the inclusion-exclusion on the objects you *do* pick, rather than the ones you *don't*, which leads to the somewhat simpler $$E_k(m)=\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\left\{m\sum_{u=0}^{k-m}\left[(-1)^u{n+m+u-k \choose u}\sum_{J\subseteq I; |J|=k-m-u}\left(\sum_{j\in J}p_j\right)^k\right]\right\}$$ which is easier to simplify, but again, not much point in using this now that Did got it down to $k-n+\sum_i \left(1-p_i\right)^k$

Comment: Re "a long way", see comment on main.

Comment: @Did wow, nice.