# Duplicate permutation vectors of a independently-column-shuffled row-wise matrix partition.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

## Problem specification

Suppose we have a matrix $A$ of size $(n, m)$ with elements $A_{i,j}$ with $i \in [0, n)$ and $j \in [0, m)$. Now, we partition the matrix randomly into $n$ vectors this way: for each $j$, we let $\pi_j(i) \in [0, n)$ (= a random permutation of row indices) and then the $n$ vectors $v$ indexed by $i$ will be $v_i = [A_{\pi_0(i), 0},\ A_{\pi_1(i), 1},\ A_{\pi_2(i), 2},\ ...,\ A_{\pi_m(i), m}]$.

Here's my crude visualization of those vectors $v_i$.
[image]

Let us also assume that $A$ always contains the same, distinct elements (imagine whole numbers from $0$ to $n \times m - 1$ for example).

What I'm interested in is that, given an integer $K$ and the matrix size $n$ and $m$, if we split the same matrix $A$ into $n$ vectors $v_i$ $K$ times, and after each partitioning of $A$ add all of those vectors $v_i$ into a single set (which will contain $n \times K$ elements at the end), what is the *expected amount of duplicate vectors in the set* ?

## My insights

I've acquainted myself with the basic combinatorics, but this is a problem currently beyond my reach (and before you ask, no, this is not a school homework puzzle, but a problem arisen from my investigation of student task distributions in a research project, detes irrelevant).

I've observed that the total amount of different partitions into $v_i$ is, hopefully, $n^m \cdot (n-1)^m \cdot (n-2)^m\ ...\ 1^m$, or $(n!)^m$, and every vector $v_i$ has the same probability of occuring, that is, $\frac{1}{n^m}$, but otherwise, the fact that the individual vectors within a single partition are highly dependent on one another is just... perplexing to me. I'm unsure if I can use [this answer about duplicate counts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988021/how-to-compute-the-expected-number-of-duplicates) to just claim that the answer to my problem is simply $Kn - n^m + \sum_{i=0}^{n^m - 1} (1 - \frac{1}{n^m})^{Kn}$ because the vectors are definitely not independently generated.

I will appretiate anything you'll be able to add to the topic, thank you very much.

### EDIT (duplicate count definition):

I let the "amount of duplicates" be $\sum_{C \in equivalence\_partition} (|C| - 1)$, so, e.g. if we had a set $\{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3\}$, the sum would yield *sum for zeroes* + *sum for ones* + *sum for twos* + *sum for threes* = $(3-1) + (2-1) + (1-1) + (1-1) = 2 + 1 + 0 + 0 = 3$.

The equivalence relation on the set of all $v_i$ after $K$ samples is trivial.

Comment: if the same vector appears three times does that count as $1$?

Comment: @HereToRelax Sorry for late response. I haven't properly defined the notion of "amount of duplicates", so I will add that to my question.

Comment: With that definition of duplicate it becomes a bit more tricky but the idea is similar.

Comment: @HereToRelax I'm currently grasping your answer. Give me a few minutes :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the $n^m$ vectors what is the expected duplication count?

Suppose the vector $v$ contains $A_{i,1}$. Then the vector that contains $A_{i,1}$ in each of the partitions is $v$ with probability $\frac{1}{n^{m-1}}$. It follows the probability that the vector $v$ appears exactly $s$ times is  $\binom{K}{s}(1-\frac{1}{n^{m-1}})^{K-s}(\frac{1}{n^{m-1}})^s$. Hence the expected "duplication count" for each vector is $\sum\limits_{s=2}^K (s-1)\binom{K}{s}(1-\frac{1}{n^{m-1}})^{K-s}(\frac{1}{n^{m-1}})^s$.

From the principle of linearity of expectation, it follows that the total expected duplication count is:

$n^m\sum\limits_{s=2}^K \binom{K}{s}(s-1)(1-\frac{1}{n^{m-1}})^{K-s}(\frac{1}{n^{m-1}})^s$.

Comment: Basically the important hint is: In each partition there is only one vector that contains $A_{1,j}$ for each $j$. and every possible vector has the same probability.

Comment: I realized I used $i$ twice for different things. So I added an $s$ variable.

Comment: I believe there might have been a misunderstandment. Are you sure we're looking for *full duplicate vectors*, like $[0, 1, 5, 3] = [0, 1, 5, 3]$, and not only the duplicates of individual members of $A$? If that was not clear from the question, sorry, I'll add more info. If you did in fact understand this and your answer encorporates this fact, then let me know.

So e.g.: {[0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2], [2, 3, 4], [0, 3, 2]} has two duplicate vectors [0, 3, 2].

Comment: I am looking for full duplicate vectors. Each partition gives us $n$ vectors, and each of these vectors contains one of the values in the first column, right?

Comment: Each partition gives us $n$ vectors, yes, and each of those $n$ vectors contains exactly one value from the first column, just like in the picture.

Comment: Since you are a programmer perhaps you can montecarlo it and compare?

Comment: I have simulated this, multiple times, and got some results, but I'd like to explain where these results come from.

Comment: Well, the "key" idea is that for each vector the distribution for the number of times the vector can appear is manegeable. This is because in each partition that vector appears independently, with probability $\frac{1}{n^{m-1}}$. This is because there is exactly one vector that contains the "correct" value from the first column in the partition, and this vector can have each of the combinations for the other columns with the same probability.

Comment: That kind of does make sense to me, but why are we sticking to the notion of "correct value from the *first* column"? Shouldn't we care about other columns also? EDIT: wait, let me think for a second

Comment: In the partition there is going to be exactly one vector of the form $(a,?,?,?,?)$ and each of these occurs with the same probability.

Comment: I completely understand the fact that, given a random partition, the probability that a vector $(a, ?, ?, ?, ...)$ occurs is exactly $\frac{1}{n^{m-1}}$. I unfortunately fail to follow how that relates to the original problem (thank you for your -- hopefully not depleted --patience :D). Give me a few minutes, I'll figure it out eventually.

Comment: Because all of the partitions are independent between each other, this information allows us to calculate the probability distribution for the random variable $X_{v}$ which tells us how many times the vector $v$ can appear. It is a geometric distribution. And knowing this we can calculate the expected "repetition" for this particular vector. Please note that each of the vectors only adds a very small amount, since the most likely outcome is that the vector appears $0$ times (unless $K$ is super large). Now, because linearity of expectation, we just need to add this value for all $n^m$ vectors.

Comment: I got it! It just completely stumped me how you could use the value of first index, that is, $A_{i, 1}$ for comparison of the vectors and the other values for the probability that the vectors are exactly the same, and that simplified the problem completely. Thank you for spending so much time on this, I'd give you a bounty if I could :D

Comment: Glad to help, I am always happy when linearity of expectation can be used for problems I hadn't seen before.